# Fetch specific columns from an entity but not the entire entity

Tags: quarkus, quarkus-panache

I have an entity:

```
@Entity
public class MailingList extends PanacheEntity{
public String name;
public String email;
public Organization organization;
.
.
.
}
```

So, I am trying to write a query to simply return me a list having the id and email only but not a list of the MailingList entities. I am using MySQL and I want something as shown [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/selecting-columns.html). I have read through different documentation but I haven't found something to solve my problem. Please help out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes,

With panache it is possible to use DTO projections like in hibernate or jpa.

[Here](https://quarkus.io/guides/hibernate-reactive-panache#query-projection) you have an example from the quarkus panache documentation on how to achieve a projection of only certain fields.

Comment: I have seen that, but how do I specify the exact fields I need?

Comment: @RichardMatovu The example shows that you need to create a specific class with the fields you need to select; there it is PersonName which will only retrieve the name column. `PanacheQuery<PersonName> query = Person.find("status", Status.Alive).project(PersonName.class);` tells panache that you want instances of Person, but only with the fields specified by PersonName

Comment: Thank you @RamiroGonzálezMaciel. That explains it